# Oracle generating hash_val from a clob

Tags: oracle, ddl, hashing

I have the following table, where I would like the value of hash_val to be generated from clob_val whether clob_val is inserted or updated.

Can this be done perhaps by making the column hash_val a virtual column? Or does this have to be done via a function and trigger.

I want to use something like the CRYPTO call below to generate the value for hash_val. In addition, I would like hash_val to be the primary KEY

Any examples  setting up the virtual column if possible would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all who answer.

```
CREATE table table_z(
seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
val NUMBER, 
hash_val VARCHAR2(1000), 
clob_val CLOB);

DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH (clob_val, 6                          /*DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH512*/                                              )
```

Comment: Take a look at the Oracle documentation on virtual columns; and primary keys.  It looks like you **might** be able to create a primary key on a virtual column.  See "Notes" https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__BABIJIHJ "Restrictions"  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__BABIIGBD

Comment: Note that DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH returns a RAW datatype, not VARCHAR2. You need to store it as RAW: casting or converting to VARCHAR2 will invalidate the hash result.

Comment: @pmdba thanks for responding. I'm not seeing a problem. Can you provide a simple test CASE to prove your point.

Comment: RAW output is binary data. Storing it as VARCHAR2 applies a character set conversion that is not valid for binary data. What you see after the varchar2 conversion will be missing content, even if it _looks_ valid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax for `CREATE TABLE` that will allow you to automatically update a value of a column due to a DML operation.

If the function is deterministic, you might be able to define that column as a Virtual Column instead. (I don't know if VC supports LOBs).

Alternatively, you'll need to do the update in a Trigger. (Again, I'm concerned with limitations due to LOBs).

If all else fails, you'll need to restrict DML operations to a Table API (TAPI); the collection of procedures are stored in a Package.

Comment: thanks for responding. It's not the CLOB I want to change it's the hash_val that will change, which is based on the CLOB.